# How to identify all the resources created by me in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm from Azure background and trying to learn AWS.

I'm creating multiple services/resources like EC2, S3, Lambda, etc in my AWS account.  I'm not a root user.

My question
How can I find/list all the resources created by me?  I want the ability to quickly see/list all the resources created by me to do cleanup.
Note: In Azure, I can do this by creating resources under a specific Resource group or I can tag them, later I can open a specific resource group to find all the resources that I've created or filter by tag.  Is there any similar feature in AWS?

Thanks

Comment: There is no such tool provided by AWS.

Comment: You can tag many resources in AWS as well. You just need to manually do that all the time, which is not convenient.

Comment: This is an excellent question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First approach:**

There is no single command that can list all resources in an AWS account.

You should use the AWS Management Console or make API calls to any service, in any region, to get a list of the resources created.

A good place to start is the *billing console*, which can show you which services have been used in which region. You can then log into any of these services and regions to see the resources.

**Second approach:**

You can use the **AWS Configuration Service** to create an inventory of all your AWS resources for supported AWS services. An inventory acts as a CMDB for your AWS landscape and records all configuration changes.

To know how to configure, refer [here](https://cloudaffaire.com/how-to-get-all-resources-deployed-in-aws/)

**Third approach:**

You can also use **Tag Editor** which will also allows you to edit the tags for all your AWS resources.

To know how to configure, refer [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-list-all-resources)